# C++ Error: no matching function for call to 'toupper'

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code raises the *no matching function for call to 'toupper'* error (C++ 11):

```
string s("some string");
if (s.begin() != s.end())
{
    auto it = s.begin();
    it=toupper(it);
}
```

This code is from C++ primer, fifth edition, chapter 3, about "introducing iterators".

Do you know why this error?

Comment: You have to dereference `it` before passing into `toupper` - `*it = toupper(*it);`. There is no overload of toupper which takes iterator.

Comment: `s[0] = (char)toupper(s[0]);`

Comment: @Hermann Are you sure there isn't a problem with how the ebook is displayed for you? It says `*it = toupper(*it)` in the version I have and that would be a very blatant error.

Comment: @Walnut: this is the same in the PDF. However, as a C++ newbie, I don't understand the subject very well yet so I could be wrong somewhere. Futhermore this book is a reference so the error is probably on my side. In consequence I delete the mention of an error in the book, in the doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to include the appropriate headers, in this case `<string>` and `<cctype>`.
2. You need to specify the namespaces, in this case `std::` (use say `using namespace std`, but that is not a good idea).
3. `it` is not a character. It is an *iterator* into the string. Think of it as a pointer-like object. When you want to change a character pointed to by `p`, you would say `*p = do_something_with(*p)`, not `p = do_something_with(p)` which would change the pointer.

Thus if we write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s("some string");
    if (s.begin() != s.end()) {
        auto it = s.begin();
        *it = std::toupper(*it);
    }
}
```

then this [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/tvg89U) (GodBolt.org).

Comment: Thank you einpoklum for this explanation!